How to derive D brane effective action? The result is super Yang-Mills action
It is said that the effective action on $N$ coincident D branes is $U(N)$ super Yang-Mills (SYM) action with 16 super charges.
On D3 branes it is $4d,\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM
$$
L = -\int d^4x. Tr[ \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^2 + \frac{1}{2} (D_\mu X_m)^2 + \frac{i}{2}\overline{\lambda}\Gamma^\mu D_\mu \lambda - \frac{1}{2}\overline{\lambda} \Gamma^m [X_m, \lambda] - \frac{1}{4} [X_m,X_n]^2].
$$
It is said to be derived from the action on $Dp$-branes
$$
S_{Dp} = S_{DBI} + S_{CS} = -T_{Dp}\int d^{p+1}\sigma. e^{-\Phi(X)} \sqrt{-\det(G_{ab} + 2\pi\alpha’ F_{ab} - B_{ab})}
+ \mu_p \int C_{RR} \wedge \exp(2\pi\alpha’ F+B)
$$
and first derive $10d,\mathcal{N}=1$ SYM and then dimensionally reduce to $4d$.
But I haven’t found any reference that derive this clearly, neither in textbooks I read (David Tong’s string theory) or in google search. Everyone seems to either already know that or be convenient to just admit that.

did you try searching in the book called D-Branes by Clifford Johnson?
